# Azure mobile service auto-login with Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm brand new to Xamarin and playing around with a simple cross-platform app.

The app connects to an Azure Mobile Service, and requires login which I've set up server-side [following tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication/):  and client-side [following tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users/).

Everything works fine! However, the current implementation requires you to login everytime you start the app. **How can i cache the user credentials and auto-login as long as you don't log out?**

I've tried something like this, but obviously didn't work:
When a user is logging in I save (I'm not calling directly to MobileServiceClient, just showing you a snippet):

```
 var userId = MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.UserId;
 var authToken = MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
```

So i store these two strings, and when I next time open the app I try to:

```
CurrentClient.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(userId);
CurrentClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = authToken;
```

As I said this does not seem to be the correct way since it does not work. What is the correct way to cache and auto-login an user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move over to a CLIENT-FLOW - in client-flow authentication, you use the client SDK provided by the auth provider and then pass that token silently to Azure Mobile Apps to authenticate there.  Check out Chapter 2 of my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer. I've been looking around chapter 2 in your book, and that seems very nice and informative. I'm a little in how the server configuration differs from a server-flow authentication and a client-flow. It seems like the server are setup the same way, but the difference is how the client acts. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Yes - the server is set up identically.  The client presents the credentials and then passes the auth token to the backend for validation.